# Marshalling LPDWORD into C# for P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a C++ function (WinAPI) with the following signature:

```cpp
__declspec(dllimport) LPDWORD WINAPI MyFunction(HDET hDet, WORD wStartChan, WORD wNumChans,
    LPDWORD lpdwBuffer, LPWORD lpwRetChans, LPDWORD lpdwDataMask,
    LPDWORD lpdwROIMask, LPCSTR lpszAuth);
```

I have one example of it being called in C++, which is as follows:

```cpp
::MyFunction((HDET)pUConn->GetHDET(), (WORD)lStartChan, (WORD)lNumChans,
                &(m_DataCache[lView].pdwChans[lStartChan]), &wRetChans,
                &(m_DataCache[lView].dwDataMask), &(m_DataCache[lView].dwROIMask),
                pUConn->GetAuthorization());
//m_DataCache[lView].pdwChans is an array of DWORDs. (Declared as DWORD * pdwChans;)
```

Now, I can marshal all of the parameters except the 4th. It's a pointer to an array of `DWORD`s. That makes me think `int **`.  However, when I pass in a `ref int[]` I get back `null`. Here's my C# declaration:

```cs
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("MCBCIO32.dll", EntryPoint = "MIOGetData")]
public static extern IntPtr MIOGetData(int hDet, ushort sChan, ushort nChan,
ref int[] Buffer, ref short rchan, ref int datamask, ref int roimask, string auth);
```

I've also tried `IntPtr` and a simple `int[]`. `Int[]` returns an array of 0s. `IntPtr` is interesting, (interesting but wrong) - it gives me back weird values, non-zero but clearly incorrect. And they change every time I do another run, so I think I'm wandering around in random memory. I marshal memory for the buffer and copy it over as follows:

```cs
/***Snip***/
int arrsize = 100;
int[] buffer = new int[arrsize];

short rchan = -1;
IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(arrsize * sizeof(int));
int datamask = 0, roimask = 0;
MCBWrapper.FUNC(hDet, 0, 1, p, ref rchan, ref datamask, ref roimask, "");
Marshal.Copy(p, buffer, 0, arrsize);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
p = IntPtr.Zero;
for (int r = 0; r < arrsize; r++)
{
    Console.Write($"{buffer[r]} ");
}
```

In this case, the buffer is marshaled as `IntPtr`.
I have tried a few other ways of marshaling but to little effect. `IntPtr` seems the most promising. I've also tried using a `ref` to an `IntPtr` (with nearly identical code), and it gives me similar results to a single indirection.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this - I'm not used to working with marshaling.

Comment: I always found dllimport/pinvoke method to be of too low quality to use in actual products. The garbage collector can move stuff around (so C++ should not hold on to pointers etc). I advise you to learn a bit of C++/cli (not too hard). [introduction here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes). You might also want to read up on pinning memory when interacting with C++

Comment: `It's a pointer to an array of DWORDs` - no, it's a pointer to `DWORD`, which may or may not mean an array of `DWORD`s. The C# translation of that is `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] Buffer`.

Comment: Arrays are already marshaled as a pointer to their first element.  So Buffer needs to be int[], no ref.

Comment: `pinvoke` - the 'no it isn't' answer to the question 'is using c# easy?'

Comment: Thanks all. In my defense, `int[]` is the first thing I tried- but nChans functions as the length of the copy, and the first 10 or so members being copied are all 0.  So it only looked like the array was coming back unmodified.  Facepalm.

Comment: Note the `LPDWORD*` in the question title is inaccurate, the actual C++ code is just `LPDWORD`

Comment: @PaulSanders I think it's interacting with C++ that isn't easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a `**` pointer-to-pointer. It's just a pointer. So you need to pass in a buffer. So it's `int[]` not `ref int[]`.

The buffer size looks like it's being passed in as `nChan`, and the used length of the buffer is passed back in `rchan`. You specify that using `SizeParamIndex`.

You also need to specify `LPStr` on the final string parameter.

The usage of the other two `ref` parameters are unclear, they should probably be either `[In] in` or `[Out] out`. Also `HDET` is unclear what size it is.

```cs
[DllImport("MCBCIO32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr MIOGetData(
  int hDet,
  ushort sChan,
  ushort nChan,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 4)] int[] Buffer,
  [Out] out short rchan,
  ref int datamask,
  ref int roimask,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string auth);
```

You use it like this

```cs
int arrsize = 100;
int[] buffer = new int[arrsize];
int datamask = 0, roimask = 0;

var result = MCBWrapper.FUNC(hDet, 0, 1, buffer, out var rchan, ref datamask, ref roimask, "");

for (int r = 0; r < arrsize; r++)
{
    Console.Write($"{buffer[r]} ");
}
```

Note that if you *did* need to use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, you must make sure to free the memory in a `finally` to prevent leaks.